# React Native + Redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am creating an application with React native + Redux and I am new to Redux so I already know that in React native all Apis are converted into Java or Objective-C but what about Redux code, is it converting too into Java or objective-c ?

Answer (score 1):

No it will not convert into any other language.

Redux is simply a state management library where you can track your state or modify it easily. The main purpose of using Redux is that you can modify or access your same state from any React component.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read an article about React Native architecture or even better - watch Tadeu Zagallo talk about how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ah2qNbI40vE

Simply said - most of the APIs are shimmed and backed by native implementation (e.g. fetch, AsyncStorage), though your application logic is running inside a Javascript VM (that also includes Redux, action creators, reducers etc).

So answering your question more specifically, your application logic is a Javascript code running inside a Javascript VM whereas APIs in most cases are native. Note that it's still possible to have more advanced logic computation done with Objective-C or Java as a part of a custom native module.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Grabowski

Answer (score 0):

React Native will ensure that your redux code runs in a so called JavaScriptCore, which is a framework to "evaluate JavaScript programs from within an app, and support JavaScript scripting of your app. [[Futher Information]](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore)"